# Docker do not work from build remotely at Jenkins slave. What' the reason?

Tags: jenkins, docker, agent, slave

At CentOS VM Docker was set up and working great.
This VM was attached to Jenkins as slave.
Jenkins agent is run as login same as login to be used for Docker.

When "docker ps", or another docker command, is launched at the VM from in-line script from Jenkins, it reports: Docker service not started.

Looks like unsifficient privilegies. But... when launched locally - it works. And login is the same.

What is the reason of failure? SELinux need tweaks?